# What is the meaning of the range and the precision?

Tags: terminology, computer-science, floating-point

Using the **scientific notation**:

$$3.14 = 0.314 \times 10^1$$

From Tanenbaum's *Structured Computer Organization*, section B.1:

> The **range** is effectively determined by the number of digits in the exponent and the **precision** is determined by the number of digits in the fraction.

**I know how this notation works but I am asking about the meaning of the two words.**

Why the book is calling them the range and precision? What do they exactly mean?

Comment: Does this help? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *range* is determined by the biggest and smallest (positive) numbers you can represent. Clearly, with two digits in the exponent you can write numbers from approximately $10^0$ (or $10^{-99}$ if you allow signs) to $10^{99}$ (even more by clever choce of mantissa). With one-digit exponents the range is much smaller: from $10^{-9}$ to $10^{9}$.

The *precision* is determined by the smallest (relative) difference between two representable numbers. The difference between $3.14$ and $3.15$ is about $0.3\%$ of the values (and also the difference between $6.02\cdot 10^{23}$ and  $6.03\cdot 10^{23}$ or between $1.60\cdot 10^{-19}$ and $1.61\cdot 10^{-19}$ is of the same - relative - magnitude. On the other hand $3.1415926535897932384626433$, $6.02214129\cdot10^{26}$ and $1.602176565\cdot10^{-19}$ carry a lot more precision. The latter two are numerical values for the Avogadro constant and the elementary charge. Obtaining thes values required very *precise* measurements. The precision does not depend on the exponent. That is, if the value of $e$ in other unit systems is $1.602176565\cdot10^{6}$, the same careful prcision in the measurements is required to obtain so many digits.